# Verify if two columns aren't sort in asc in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out a result of a query but didn't manage to do it, i have four columns:

```
ID   Nr  Date       Payment
100  1   10012020   99
100  2   10022020   87
100  3   10032020   75
```

The 'Nr' column and 'Date' column are linked meaning that the value 1 from 'Nr' column has to match with the lowest date from the 'Date' column, value 2 with the second lowest date and so on.

The problem is that i have some ID's which values from 'Nr' column and 'Date' column doesn't match, meaning i have something like this:

```
 ID   Nr  Date       Payment
 200  3   10012020   99
 200  1   10022020   87
 200  2   10032020   75
```

How can i find the ID's that has the nonmatching between 'Nr' column and 'Date' column ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your Date's column data type is Date you can use `LEAD()` and `LAG()` window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
  select *,
    lag(date) over (order by Nr) previous_date,
    lead(date) over (order by Nr) next_date
  from tablename
) t
where t.date < t.previous_date or t.date > t.next_date
```

It is not clear from your sample data if the ordering that you want to apply should affect the whole table or just each `ID`.
If it is the latter case then the `over` clauses should include `partition`:

```
select t.*
from (
  select *,
    lag(date) over (partition by ID order by Nr) previous_date,
    lead(date) over (partition by ID order by Nr) next_date
  from tablename
) t
where t.date < t.previous_date or t.date > t.next_date
```

Comment: Hi forpas, thank you for your answer, unfortunately the Date column is integer.

Comment: If it is an integer in the format of your sample data then it is not comparable.